# Issue in npm config issue, stuck at loading phase

Tags: react-360

installed successfully   "sudo npm install -g react-360-cli"
and created project  "react-360 init helloDev"
when press the "npm install"  its stuck somewhere and not load the project

before the react360 modules were not downloaded properly then it shows to update the yarm. after those modules were downloaded but the issue was created in npm Start[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WIhN.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. Any research?

Answer (score 0):

http://localhost:8081/index.html after this url post in browser further modules loaded and project render on Browser